# How to work with props created out of Apollo Client returned query result in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I have followed some blog tutorial on GraphQL and was able to tie together my GraphQL query with the React component that's supposed to display the returned result.  This works when I do console.log of `this.props`.

As my next step, I would actually like to reference the individual data members inside the props (that were placed there by GraphQL) -- something like `props.Security.loading` -- and this is where it all falls apart.

Ideally, I would simply like to use "any" somewhere in the typing and avoid this hassle, but I can also explicitly specify in the interface(s) all the data that can come back (which, I think, defeats the purpose of GraphQL).  So how do I do this?  It seems that when I comment out the "data: Security" line out of the Props interface, the code compiles.   Thoroughly confused here.  Thank you

```
import * as React from "react";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";

const getSymbolInfoQuery = gql` {
                Security(id: "MSFT") {
                  id
                }   
             } `;

interface Security {
  loading: Boolean;
}

interface Props {
  data: Security
}

class ProductChecker extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.displaySearchFilters()}</div>;   
  }

  displaySearchFilters() {
    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <div>Hello there</div>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(getSymbolInfoQuery)(ProductChecker);
```

Error on the very last "export" line:

```
   Error: [ts]
    Argument of type 'typeof ProductChecker' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>>'.
      Type 'typeof ProductChecker' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>, any>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type 'Partial<DataProps<{}, {}>> & Partial<MutateProps<{}, {}>>' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
            Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
              Type 'DataValue<{}, {}> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Security'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Security'. [2345]
    class ProductChecker
```

Comment: Do you strictly want to stick to `graphql` or is using `WithApolloClient` an option for you by fetching data using an injected client in the `componentDidMount` method?

Comment: I dont have a preferred method -- I am learning and trying to get it to work.  What are you suggesting?  thank you

Comment: It is slightly more convoluted as it contains other logic as well, but take a look at this code: https://github.com/comsysto/pokemon-trivia-challenge/blob/98121cf3e10b311b16ad66c2f9d3745ec23cd1d6/packages/client/src/routes/quiz/containers/EncounterContainer.tsx If you want to give it a try using `WithApolloClient`, `withApollo` and the injected `client` in the props and it turns out to work properly, I can write down a proper answer.

Comment: ouch, I had looked, but it is a few magnitudes over my head.  Any possibility to distill it down a bit?  I am an ungrateful beggar here, sorry, will keep trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```js
import { graphql, ChildDataProps } from 'react-apollo'

type TSecurity = {
  loading: Boolean;
}
type TProps = {
  data: TSecurity
}
// ChildDataProps<InputProps, Response, Variables>
type TChildProps = ChildDataProps<{}, TProps , {}>

// graphql<InputProps, Response, Variables, ChildProps>()
graphql<{}, TProps, {}, TChildProps>(getSymbolInfoQuery)(ProductChecker)
```

more info about using Apollo with TypeScript is [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/static-typing#typing-components)

Answer (score -4):

```
displaySearchFilters() { console.log(this.props); }
```

this should go above the render